# Reading in a DLL file and passing the value to the main application

Tags: dll, c++builder

Below are three ways to use the DLL and I don't know which way is the correct one for returning the result to the main application. The last example with "ReadTextFileFunc2()" function using the structure returns an error in the form of "access violation" in line:

```
DLLStruct struc = readTextFile2();
```

```
*(struc.sText) = StrNew( L"Test" );
```

The first two examples work, but I doubt if it's just a coincidence.

Main app

```
#include "Struct.h"

{
  typedef void (*ReadTextFileFunc)(String&);
  typedef String* (*ReadTextFileFunc1)();

    HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibraryA( "DLL.dll" );

    if (hDLL == NULL)
    {
        Memo1->Lines->Append( L"Nie można załadować biblioteki DLL!" );
        return;
    }

    ReadTextFileFunc readTextFile = (ReadTextFileFunc)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "_ReadTextFile");
    ReadTextFileFunc1 readTextFile1 = (ReadTextFileFunc1)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "_ReadTextFile1");

typedef DLLStruct (*ReadTextFileFunc2)();
  typedef void (*Free)(DLLStruct*);

if (readTextFile == NULL || readTextFile1 == NULL ) {

        Memo1->Lines->Append( L"Nie można znaleźć funkcji w bibliotece DLL!");
        FreeLibrary(hDLL);
        return;
    }


    String fileContent;
    readTextFile(fileContent);
    Memo1->Lines->Append( fileContent );

    String* fileContent1 = readTextFile1();
    Memo1->Lines->Append( *fileContent1 );
    delete fileContent1;

    String* fileContent2;
    DLLStruct struc = readTextFile2();
    fileContent2 = struc.sText;
    free( &struc );
    Memo1->Lines->Append( *fileContent2 );

    FreeLibrary(hDLL);

}
```

File in DLL

```
#include "Struct.h"

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void ReadTextFile( String& fileContent )
{
    fileContent = "Test";
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) String* ReadTextFile1()
{
    String* fileContent = new String();

    *fileContent = "Test";

    return fileContent;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DLLStruct ReadTextFile2()
{
   DLLStruct struc = {0};
                                    
   *struc.sText = StrNew( L"Test" );

   return struc;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) void Free( DLLStruct* s )
{
  if( s && s->sText ) { StrDispose( reinterpret_cast<char*>(s->sText) ); s->sText = NULL; }
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Struct.h

```
struct DLLStruct
{
    String* sText;
};
```